# Xamarin.Forms: Synchronization with Azure MobileServices too slow

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.forms, synchronization, azure-mobile-services

I'm trying to implement Azure MobileServices in Xamarin.Forms, following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/mobile-apps/azure-mobile-apps/quickstarts/xamarin-forms/offline
but I noticed that synchronization is very slow. For example, I synchronized a db containing 15 tables and about 60k records, and the entire process required about 6 mins! The result changes a little if I rerun the operation on a db already synchronized.
Does it possible to improve entire process?
I have some doubts that the technology is already used extensively, because there is very little documentation on internet and it is often out of date.
In this case, what are the alternatives?

Comment: please show me your code

Comment: It's worth noting that Offline sync for SQL and Xamarin Forms has reached end of life. I've heard some folks mention that it's probably best to just implement it manually. I've worked with manual and offline services. Manual is a bit more tedious, but does work a lot better.

Comment: @Janwilx72: Thx. Indeed, after a lot of research on the net, I realize that this technology is no longer supported. At this moment, I'm taking a look here: https://dotmimsync.readthedocs.io/Overview.html. Seems to be the best alternative.

Comment: Offline sync for SQL and Xamarin Forms is still supported.  I am the person supporting it.  There is a new version out last November, and I'm working on a new (.NET MAUI compatible) library and ASP.NET Core edition.  Not sure where you got the "not supported from"

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, 60K records takes a long time to synchronize the first time.  It's inevitable because of the amount of data to transfer.  6 minutes is not a surprise.

However, you should have implemented the appropriate stuff for incremental sync.  That includes ensuring your model has the UpdatedAt and CreatedAt timestamps, plus a globally unique ID, and naming your query when you use `PullAsync()`.  Something like:

```
await mTable.PullAsync('allItems', mTable.CreateQuery());
```

More information: https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps/howto/client/dotnet/#syncing-an-offline-table